# error 5 when starting a service

Tags: c++, service, windows-7, admin

i created a windows service in c++ and when i try start the service i get the message error 5: access denied.

[image]

my user account is set to admin and i even tried using the default admin account on the computer and it still doesn't work.

i can install/uninstall the service through the cmd without problems but i can't start the service

the code isn't the problem here its the user account. any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Running a service" is not simply "starting a program on my desktop". It does not necessarily run as "you".

The service is detached from any desktops and it actually ignores your user account. The service will have its own account/password configuration stored in the OS and when you run it, you only order it to start up. It will startup on its own user account. If you have put your .exe/.dll files in some protected folder, and if you have not configured neither the accessrights to that files nor user-pass for the service, then there's great odds that the service tries to run at default service user account like 'LocalService' or 'NetworkService' and that it simply cannot touch the files.

If you installed the service properly, go to ControlPanel - AdministrativeTools - Services, find your service and check the (if I remember well) second tab and verify that the username presented here has access to the files that are tried to be loaded and run. If the username is wrong, correct it. If you don't care about the username, then just peek that name and set accessrights on the folder and/or files such that **at least** both "read directry contents" and "read" and "execute" are available for that-username-the-service-tries-to-run-as.

Comment: the service is set to run on the Local Service account and changing it the network service doesn't fix the problem. the folder where the service is saved in my desktop

Comment: I did not suggest you to set it to a 'NetworkService'. If I remember correctly, both NetworkService and LocalService by default does not have access to /Users/* folders, your Desktop included. First, try assigning proper PERMISSIONS to that folder-that-lies-where-you-like. It's under the rightclick in the Properties in the Security tab. If you don't like messing with that settings, you may in turn try setting the service to run as YOUR account (with your password) instead of xyzService. Then, the service will run truly as You and will have access to everything you can access by yourself.

Comment: what permissions to i need to set? yes the service works if i set the account to my user account but i would just like it to work automatically instead of me having to go into the SCM and setting the account. This service will be passed on to other people and they can't be expected to set it to their account when they want to use the service

Comment: in the program the code to set the account is #define SERVICE_ACCOUNT L"NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService". is there a way to get the user account automatically? or can LocalService be able to run the service?

Comment: Both options are possible. First, getting the username is possible but is probably a wrong idea. What if the target computer has three or more accounts? Would the 'current' be ok, or maybe that second or third? How'd you get passwords for them? The OS will never give you those passwords. Also, running the service silently at user's account is not good from security reasons: your service can theoretically access to all their files and most users will NOT like that. If you still want that, you should provide two textboxes in your service installer that will ask for the username and password.

Comment: i'm not really worried about security right now. i need the service to run automatically without asking the user anything. so how can i get LocalService/NetworkService to work?

Comment: The second option is also possible. Most of services use the LocalService or NetworkService accounts especially to not run as any user and to not have access to the user's files and to not have to guess the passwords. You should install it to non-Desktop location that will be accessible without special real-USER rights, for example the famous "\Program Files\MyService" (or even direct "C:\MyService", but that's not as pretty). Once the service has its own dedicated folder, you can set set read/execute or even "full access" permissions to that folder for the useraccount the service will use.

Comment: You can even create a brand new user account, passwordless or with some chosen password, and run the service as that special user. Just be sure to set the permissions on the folder so that this user will able to "see" and "read" the files. You can set the permissions on a folder by rightclick and properties and the security tab. If you don't see it, you may have to enable it first. Give traverse/read/execute permissions or just give 'full control' permission. If you REALLY don't care, you can give full-control permission to a user called 'everyone' and run service as literally any useraccount.

Comment: so as long as the file is in a non-desktop location then it should run on any computer?

Comment: Up to now I was talking about doing everything manually. All of that things may be done automatically by your service installer, but if you are writing it manually instead of using some general-purpose installers, you will have quite a lot to do. Copying files, creating folders, setting permissions, creating accounts etc etc, and add to that the UAC thing that will deny you access to program files, and probably a few things more. Everything is described on MSDN. I'm not trying to scare you off. Just please look around a bit and you'll probably find a ready-to-use solutions.

Comment: Lisa, the location is irrelevant. The access permissions are. Even if the file is located at desktop, if you set the permissions properly on that file/folder, than any useraccount of your choice will be able to run it. If you set the special user "everyone" and "fullcontrol", then it really will be open for everyone. The point is that if you are going to give your service to other people who will know about "all the stuff" less than me or you, then you should not give them a piece of code that will open them to hackers or accidentially erase all their files because you had a typo in your code.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to show you a bigger picture, even if everyone/fullaccess will be enough. Excuse me now, I'm "signing off", I think I explained things enough. All the rest you can find on google by simple topic searches. See you!